OpenXML body.Elements<Paragraph>() Empty When Extracting Paragraphs from DOCX in .NET 8
I'm working on a .NET 8 project where I need to read the contents of a DOCX file with exact formatting (spaces, line break and paragraph break) using the WordprocessingDocument class from the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging namespace.
I have confirmed that the DOCX file contains text content, but when I try to extract paragraphs, the body.Elements<Paragraph>() collection appears to be empty, resulting in the loop not executing. However, I am able to extract the plain text content by calling body.InnerText.
Here’s a snippet of my current code:
private string ReadDocxContentWithExactFormatting(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
        {
            StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            // This loop is not running because 
            foreach (var paragraph in body.Elements<Paragraph>())
            {
                // Intended to process the paragraph text
            }

            return contentBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return $"Error reading file: {ex.Message}";
    }
}


The body.Elements<Paragraph>() collection seems to be empty, so the loop doesn't execute. I’ve confirmed that the DOCX file contains text content, but it appears that the paragraphs aren’t being recognized. I would expect the paragraphs to be available for processing.
How can I correctly extract paragraphs with their exact formatting?

it turns out that i was using wrong namespace.

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
these are the correct namespaces.
